# Jmeter - Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException

Tags: jmeter

I am getting this error in a sub request while navigating to a site.The sub-request is not captured in the script but I am able to see in Results Tree. Please refer below image for details: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcv51.png)

Could someone please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not load testing `fonts.googleapis.com` host, are you?

I suggest adding the following entry to "URSs must match" section of your HTTP Request sampler (or better for [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

```
^((?!googleapis).)*$
```

This will filter out the calls to googleapis host so you could focus on your application solely.

See [Excluding Domains From The Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test) article for more detailed explanation and example on how to exclude several domains.

Comment: It worked! Yes I am not testing <fonts.googleapis.com> host but I was unable to exclude this URL by configuring in "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder". Because this is an embedded source URL. But after adding ^((?fonts.googleapis).)*$ to "URLs must match" field in "HTTP Request Defaults" element , the resource was not downloaded.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
As i am suspecting "Attached image" URL is not useful for you, and you want to
exclude that So need to uncheck "Retrieve all embedded resources" form each
```

"**HTTP REQUEST**" and "**HTTP REQUEST DEFAULTS**"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vikas, but there are many other useful sub-requests(resources) under the navigation transaction. If I uncheck "Retrieve all embedded resources" all other resources are missing from Results Tree. Is there a way to capture all embedded resources in the script while recording also ? So that I can remove unnecessary resources like "fonts.googleapi" from my script.

Comment: yes if while recording you not exclude any URL patterns. script by default record all URL's related to main URL.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see this exception - the server terminated TCP connection established between client (your Jmeter) and server (googleapi). So, Jmeter expects correct HTTP answer but receives nothing (TCP RST or FIN flag, you can check it by parsing tcpdump).

Possible reasons:

1. I don't see any cookies sent within the request. As you said, it's a sub-request. So, it should contain session cookies established by server. You can use HTTP Cookie Manager for that.
2. Your Jmeter can't establish HTTPS connection (you do use HTTPS in this request). Make sure that all is OK with your certificates/keys.